# android how todo onSingleTapUp outside my view

Tags: android, gesturedetector

Maybe im probably all wrong about this.
Here goes..
I have the:

```
gestureScanner = new GestureDetector(this);
```

and i have the:

```
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
```

The class is:

```
public class PhotoEditDrawView extends ImageView implements OnGestureListener {
```

In the `onSingleTapUp` im detecting tap's on 4 places on the screen
They are:
Left bottom
left middle
right bottom
right middle

I get click responses ok from all 4 locations if the Bitmap fills the screen.
I notice that if the loaded Bitmap is small the 4 click locations are inside the image, so to speak.
 Hope you can follow this..
If the Bitmap is small I want to detect finger tap's outside the Bitmap(imageView)..
How can i do that in a sensibly way.
I was thinking of using GestureOverlayView. But it looks like it cannot detect tapping points.
Any ide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering my own question.
see my other post:
 [How can i detect tap on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206207/how-can-i-detect-tap-on-the-screen)