# How can I detect tap on the screen?

Tags: android, gesturedetector

More specific where do I attach `OnGestureListener` so that
I can detect `onSingleTapUp` everywhere on the screen,
even if an `ImageView` take up half the screen.

Now I have the Listener on the Activity that has an ImageView.
But the Listener only fire when I click outside the ImageView.

I read and try to understand this but cannot get it right.

this code is in the Activity.

```
 public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    //addtext.setText("-" + "SINGLE TAP UP" + "-");
    //Log.d(TAG, "- + SINGLE TAP UP + - ***********************************************************************");  
    int btnsize = buttonSave.getHeight();
    int viewWidth = display.getWidth();
    int viewHeight = display.getHeight();

    // RIGHT SIDE SCREEN
    if(e.getX()> (viewWidth*0.7)){
        Log.d(TAG, "RIGHT SIDE");
        if(e.getY()> viewHeight*0.7){         
            Log.d(TAG, "right down on screen");
        }else if(e.getY()> (viewHeight*0.45)){ 
            Log.d(TAG, "right middle on screen   ");
        }
    }
    // LEFT SIDE SCREEN
    if(e.getX()< (viewWidth*0.3)){
        Log.d(TAG, "LEFT SIDE");
        if(e.getY()> viewHeight*0.7){ 
            Log.d(TAG, "Left middle on screen  ");
        }else if(e.getY()> (viewHeight*0.45)){
            Log.d(TAG, "Left down on screen ");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about this there may be a better way but you could just register the onTouchEvent to all your views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. Thanks to the above @Jason. I have registered `onTouchEvent` to all views.
It works great.

Answer (score 10):

### Detect Screen Tap

I'm answering this for those who just need a simple way to detect a tap on the screen:

1. Add an `android:onClick` value to your base/root layout (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.). You can call it anything you want, I'm naming it `screenTapped` as an example:

   ```xml
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:onClick="screenTapped">
   ```
2. Add this method to your `Activity` using the same name you specified for `onClick`:

   ```java
   public void screenTapped(View view) {
       // Your code here
   }
   ```

**Now, tapping on the screen will call the method above.**