# Is there a command to run JavaScript project on my Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, phonegap

I have a JavaScript project. It's a game which I have created using Visual Code Studio. Previously I have created it with code.org and it works fine with Android but when I convert it (website) into app (using thunkables) it need internet to play the game.

So I converted it into app with Adobe phone gap and I used `Mouse.pressedOver(sprite)`. It worked in code.org and in Visual Studio in PC it works fine it detcts the mouse click but in Android when I clicked with my fingers but it does not work is there any alternate command or any other platform to convert JavaScript file to apk?

Comment: Could the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206207/how-can-i-detect-tap-on-the-screen) possibly help?

Comment: I could not implement in my project can you help with a alternate solution

Comment: Maybe [this alternative](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/handling-click-events-button-android/) ?